# How to prove that the dual of any set is a closed convex cone?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, dual-cone

In page 3 of https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs10107-005-0690-4.pdf . It is stated that "The dual of any set is a closed convex cone". I want to know how to prove this. We formulate the problem as follows:

Given a set $K\in\mathbb{R}^n$, the dual of $K$ is defined as 
$$K^*=\{w\in\mathbb{R}^n:x^Tw\ge0,\forall x \in K\}$$
The problem is how to prove that $K^*$ is a closed convex cone?

### My thinkings

We should prove close and convex respectively.
For closeness, we can follow this: [dual cone is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1810213/dual-cone-is-closed) , which states that each $x^Tw\ge0$is a half space, therefore, $K^*$ is a intersection of halfspaces.
But how to prove convex?

Comment: The intersection of convex sets is convex (several line exercise), and half spaces are convex.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v,w \in K^*$, $x \in K$, and $\lambda \in [0,1]$.

Since $x^Tw \ge 0$ and $x^Tv \ge 0$, we have that

\begin{align*}
x^T(\lambda v + (1- \lambda)w)&= \lambda x^Tv + (1-\lambda)x^Tw \\
&\ge 0.
\end{align*}

$x$ was arbitrary, so it must be that $\lambda v + (1- \lambda)w \in K^*$.