# Prove dual cone is closed

Tags: convex-analysis

I have difficulties understanding [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1810278/831100):

> Dual cone of $C$ is defined to be
>
> $$C^*=\left\{ y \in X^*: \langle y,x\rangle \geq 0 , \forall x \in C 
> > \right\}$$
>
> For each $x$, $\left\{y :\langle y,x \rangle \geq 0\right\}$ is a
> closed half space. Hence $C^*$ is an intersection of closed
> half-spaces.

My problem is with this part:

> Hence $C^*$ is an **intersection** of closed
> half-spaces.

How can we say "for each x, $\left\{y:\langle y,x \rangle \geq 0\right\}$" is an intersection?
I'm new to convex analysis and will appreciate any explanations for this part .

Comment: Your problem seems to be with basic set theory rather than convex analysis.

Comment: @geetha290krm Maybe you are right, but please note that I've never seen this conversion before. You would call it a lack of experience and I'm here to correct my mistakes

Comment: @geetha290krm and I never accept something until I fully understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$C^*=\bigcap_{x\in C}\left\{y\in X^*:\langle y,x \rangle \geq 0\right\}.$$

More generally,
$$\left\{y\in A:\forall x\in B\quad P(x,y)\right\}=\bigcap_{x\in B}\left\{y\in A:P(x,y)\right\}.$$

This is because an element $y$ of $A$ belongs to the LHS iff $\forall x\in B\quad P(x,y)$, and to the RHS iff... same condition!

Comment: Finally, thanks!